# Time Complexity of while loop in case of while(boolean)?

Tags: java, while-loop, time-complexity

I am trying to understand time complexity calculation of a function but i am stuck at this point. Unlike **for** loop this **while** loop shown in the code below will depend on the input String length. How to calculate Time complexity for such cases?

The function Does this

> Blockquote

**Input Data:** `4Gopi7Krishna3Msc5India`

**Output Data:** `{"4":"Gopi","7":"Krishna","3":"Msc","5":"India"}`

Input data and length may vary each and every time.

```
 public static String SplitData(String input) {
     try {
         String outputJSON = "{";
         boolean run = true;
         while (run) {
             String firstChar = String.valueOf(input.charAt(0));
             int length = Integer.parseInt(firstChar);
             if (length > 0) {
                 String data = input.substring(1, (length + 1));
                 outputJSON = outputJSON + "\"" + String.valueOf(length) + "\":\"" + data + "\"";
                 if (length + 1 == input.length()) {
                     run = false;
                     outputJSON = outputJSON + "}";
                     System.out.println("TAG " + length + " LENGTH " + length + " DATA " + data + " INPUT " + input);
                 } else {
                     outputJSON = outputJSON + ",";
                     input = input.substring(length + 1, input.length());
                     System.out.println("TAG " + length + " LENGTH " + length + " DATA " + data + " INPUT " + input);
                 }
             } else //IF INPUT IS NOT VALID MAKE THE RETURN JSON NULL
             {
                 run = false;
                 outputJSON = "Invalid Input";
             }
         }
         return outputJSON;
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         return "Invalid Input";
     }
 }
```

Comment: "Unlike for loop this while loop shown in the code below will depend on the input String length." Why do think the calculation differs from that of a for-loop? Why do you think a for-loop will not depend on input-length?

Comment: Hi Fildor my question is how to frame like n+1 like that, i am confused how to do that in case of while loop like above, the above code is just an example i thought of.

Answer (score 0):

complexity depends on the number of the possible operations before the execution ends, a for loop wouldn't be faster if you don't change what is done inside.
this function could be much simpler and faster by just using String manipulation functions

```
public static void main(String args[]){


    String s = "4Gopi7Krishna3Msc5India";
    String res = "";
    String sp[] = s.split("[0-9]+");
        res += "{";
        for (int i = 0; i<sp.length; i++){
            String sss = sp[i];
            if(sss.length()==0) 
                continue;
            res += "\""+sss+"\":\""+Integer.toString(sss.length())+"\"" ;
            res += (i == (sp.length - 1))?"":",";                
        }
        res+="}";
        System.out.println(res);
}
```